# Non empty array, accessing first element: index out of range (Swift 2.0)

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, enumeration, swift2

I have an array of 4 `UIImageVIew` and array of images of variable size: `[UIImage]`.

I would like to iterate through the array of views and assign 4 last images to each view.

```
let photos = images.suffix(4)
for (index, view) in views.enumerate() {
  if index <= photos.count - 1 {
    view.image = photos[index]
  } else {
    view.image = nil
  }
}
```

Code works perfectly if there are no more than 4 elements in `images`. Then I got a crash: `fatal error: ArraySlice index out of range`.

I printed out `index` in for-loop and it seems that crash happens when index is `0`. `views.count` and `photos.count` return `4` in the same loop.

So, I get an error when accessing the first - `0` element of an non-empty array.

In Swift 1.2 this code worked flawlessly:

```
let photos = suffix(images, 4)
for (index, view) in enumerate(views) {
  if index <= photos.count - 1 {
    view.image = photos[index]
  } else {
    view.image = nil
  }
}
```

The only change after switching to 2.0 is in `suffix` and `enumerate` methods.

Does it look like a Swift 2.0 bug or am I doing something wrong?
[Link to source file](https://github.com/hyperoslo/ImagePicker/blob/swift-2.0/Source/BottomView/StackView.swift)

**Solution I've finished with:**

```
let photos = Array(images.suffix(4))
```

Should work exactly as `suffix()`  function in `Swift 1.2`

Comment: Hi I think re-implement suffix is unnecessary. Just create a new array with the slice passed in the initializer would do the trick. As swift structs is copy-on-write. so there is no performance or memory penalty.

Comment: Fujia, good solution! Updated the question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is due to a recent change to `ArraySlice`. Now indices of `ArraySlice` are not zero-based. For example, if `images.count == 10`, then `images.suffix(4).startIndex == 5`. See the release note [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Xcode/Conceptual/RN-Xcode-Archive/Chapters/xc7_release_notes.html), and search for the words *“For consistency and better composition of generic code”*.

Comment: Thank you! Any quick-fix to `ArraySlice` to make it again zero-based?

Comment: @RichardTopchiy Probably wrap the suffix slice in a new array, or 'photos[index + photos.startIndex]', I replied this on the train, not tested.

Comment: Good point! I've just re-implemented suffix() function from scratch